# Como fazer o aviso de tecla Caps Lock ativada?

Tags: javascript, html

Como fazer um aviso para quando a tecla Caps Lock estiver ativada no campo de senha?

<sup>A princípio gostaria de soluções em JavaScript puro, mas utilizando jQuery e relacionados serão aceitos.</sup>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348792/how-do-you-tell-if-caps-lock-is-on-using-javascript esse link me ajudou uma vez..

Comment: Desculpe a minha ignorância, mas não seria mai sensato e menos trabalhoso criar uma função que colocaria todos o caracteres de caixa alto em caixa baixa?

Comment: Felix, mas fazer dessa forma diminui a força da senha. Se fosse pra qualquer outro campo poderia ser até valido fazer dessa forma.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Utilize `getModifierState('CapsLock')` em um evento para detectar o estado. Exemplo funcional a seguir:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function( event ) {
  var flag = event.getModifierState && event.getModifierState('CapsLock');
  console.log( flag ? "Caps Lock ON": "Caps Lock OFF");
});
```

```html
Clique nesta área e pressione Caps Lock.
```

Todos os browsers modernos (com exceção do Opera Mini) suportam este método:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Fonte.](http://caniuse.com/#search=getModifierState)

Answer (score 2):

A lógica por trás disso é simples: verificar se a letra digitada é maiúscula, e se o shift não está pressionado:

```js
document.getElementById('txtSenha').onkeyup = function (e) {

  var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
  
  //enter, caps lock e backspace não interessam
  if(key == 13 || key == 8 || key == 46 || key == 20){
    return false;
  }
  
  //pega o último caracter digitado
 var tamanho = this.value.length
 var ultimo_caracter = this.value.substring(tamanho - 1);
  
  //Verifica se é maiúsculo, e se não é shift
  if(ultimo_caracter.toUpperCase() == ultimo_caracter 
  && ultimo_caracter.toLowerCase() != ultimo_caracter
  && !e.shiftKey)
  {
   alert('Caps Lock está pressionado!');
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="password" id="txtSenha" />
```

Este exemplo não usa JQuery. Você pode customizar também, permitir ou bloquear mais teclas, mas eu faria algo semelhante a isso mesmo

Comment: pois ele quer em javascript

Comment: É verdade, arrumei.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar `toUpperCase()` de JavaScript para saber se a letra está em maiúscula, quando o evento `keypress` de Jquery é chamado.

```js
$('#example').keypress(function(e) { 
    var s = String.fromCharCode( e.which );
    if ( s.toUpperCase() === s && s.toLowerCase() !== s && !e.shiftKey ) {
        alert('caps is on');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" id="example" />
```

Para mais informações:

**toUpperCase()**: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp

**toLowerCase()**: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp

Resposta original em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/a/896515/6647038